# Why doesn't text show up in action bar tab?

Tags: android

I am trying to populate tabs in an action bar in my app. I am using the following code.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_word_list);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++){
        String text = String.valueOf(letter);
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(text).setTabListener(this).setTag(text));
    }
```

The problem is that on the last tab, the Z doesn't show up. (I don't have enough reputation to post a screen cap)

I can touch the tab and detect the touch but the text doesn't show up.

What is going on here?

Here is a url with the screen cap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfQhe.jpg

Comment: "I don't have enough reputation to post a screen cap" -- then post the image elsewhere and link to it from here. Beyond that, please note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated with the next production version of Android.

Comment: Wow. Twenty-six navigation tabs?! You might want to rethink your UI design.

Comment: @TedHopp I am working on a concordance app. What problem do you see with having a tab for each letter of the alphabet and then jumping to the first word that begins with that letter when the tab is pressed?

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a recommended replacement for the action bar tabs?

Comment: I tend to agree with Mr. Hopp, that 26 tabs might be a bit much. I'd focus more on your search interface (e.g., get FTS indexing of SQLite going) and less on browsing by alphabet. That being said, for something like a concordance, a `ViewPager`, a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and a tabbed indicator (e.g., `PagerTabStrip`) is probably your best non-deprecated tab solution.

Comment: Somebody asked me to re-comment on this, and I stand by my existing recommendation: start by stopping using action bar tabs. Action bar tabs have sucked since they were first introduced. For example, in some screen sizes and orientations, they won't be tabs, but instead will be converted into a `Spinner`. That's part of the reason why they were deprecated in Android 5.0. There are other tab solutions; use one.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for amplifying your recommendation. At this point I would have to agree that action bar tabs suck. They seem to be buggy. I will abandon them.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but within the loop  you could add an if statement like follows and see what happens :

```
for (char letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++){
    String text = String.valueOf(letter);
    If(letter == 'Y'){
        text.setText('Z');
    }
    bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(text).setTabListener(this).setTag(text));

}
```

P.S : I don't know if this will work but i am curious about how to program will react to it. I wanted to post as a comment but not enough reputation.

Comment: that is not valid code but I think I see what you want to do. It just prints the letter Z where the Y should be. The blank tab is still on the end of all the tabs. This code follows your suggestion.
    if(letter == 'Y'){
        text = "Z";
    }